# jquery "on" properties for div get "attr" not working?

Tags: jquery, attr

jquery on click get attr

```
<div class="benzer">
      <i class="off" pk="125">click me</i>
    </div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".benzer").on("click",".off",function(){
        $pk = $(this).attr("pk");   
        console.log($pk);
    });
)};
<script>
```

"pk" get value undefined ??

help me please, jquery on properties for div get attr not working?

https://jsfiddle.net/ktb5ky46/1/

Comment: There no attribute as `pk`, So what exactly you want?

Comment: Also, what are you doing?

Comment: $pk should pk.$pk is php variable convention

Answer (score 0):

There no attribute as `pk`and `$pk` is not a variable.
`)};<script>` should be `})</script>`
**html**

```
<div class="benzer">
      <i class="off" pk="125">click me</i>
    </div>
```

**js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".benzer").on("click",".off",function(){
        pk = $(this).attr("pk");   
        console.log(pk);
    });
});
```

**edit**
ok now u added `attr pk.`
now get the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nu87wpnd/1/)

**edit**   [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktb5ky46/3/)

Comment: No "class" value I want to "pk" parameter value

Comment: there is no attribute pk.if you use pk it will give undefined

Comment: <i class="off" pk="125">click me</i> there is an attribute pk

Comment: sorry parameter is "pk" look at the question not "rel"

Answer (score 0):

Hi just use data attribute to avoid undefined pk attribute

```
<div class="benzer">
      <i class="off" data-pk="125">click me</i>
    </div>


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".off").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('data-pk'));//125
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/divakarvenu/j484e6hh/1/

Comment: What' s your problem now??